# Failed to integrate spring on a mybatis+jersey web app

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0, spring-mybatis

I've managed to complete my web application with Jersey and Mybatis, and now i've to integrate Spring on it but i get this error: **org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start**
Considering this is my first time with spring i'm sure i've done something wrong.
This is my AppContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.3.xsd
    http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">



<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}" p:user="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="10" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="dao/config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="test" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="dao" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

For the datasource i've made a file.properties with the information of the server i want to connect ( and obv. added the c3p0 jar)

I've made the Interfaces with the same name of the .xml mapper files and the methods have the same name as the id for the select/insert/update ecc.

then i've made a manager who @Autowire the above mentioned interfaces

What i am missing ? Thanks in advance

EDIT: my web.xml is structured like that:

```
<display-name>MostraPersone</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:AppContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestJersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>logic</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestJersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mostra/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this exception is usually caused by the  and  errors in the web.xml, or no corresponding or word errors or other reasons, the  and , < Servlet> and  correspond to good, it should not appear this exception